# php - Different behaviour of `DateTimeImmutable` for the same datetime value in different format

Tags: php, datetime

Let's suppose we have this date `1972-12-31 23:59:59`, if we get the `TimeStamp` for it from `DateTimeImmutable` object we will get this:

```php
$formattedDate = '1972-12-31 23:59:59';
$ts = (new DateTimeImmutable($formatedDate))->getTimestamp(); // <- 94690799
```

The problem that if you try to revers the conversion, so it becomes from timestamp into formatted date:

```php
$ts = 94690799;
$formattedDate = 
    (new DateTimeImmutable(sprintf('@%s', $ts)))->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // <- 1972-12-31 22:59:59
```

There is an hour gone in the second way.

So the million dolor question would be, which one of those timing is corresponding to the correct time?
Is this a bug? Or am I messing something in here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a DateTime object from a formatted string, it is created in your server's default timezone (see [`date_default_timezone_get`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-get.php)). But Unix timestamps don't have a timezone - they're always in UTC. So if you write:

```
(new DateTimeImmutable('1972-12-31 23:59:59'))->getTimestamp();
```

then what you're really asking PHP is *"How many seconds after 1970 **in UTC** was it, when it was that date + time **in my current timezone**"*. In your case, the server looks like it is running one hour ahead of UTC, hence the difference.

Crucially, when you do the inverse and create a DateTime object from a timestamp, the object's timezone is always set to UTC. There's a brief note about it on [this manual page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.compound.php).

If you set the default timezone to UTC before running the code, you'll see that the output matches. I've added an example here: https://3v4l.org/2Rfp3